# Добавить get к строке

Tags: php

Как правильно добавить к url'у get параметр, если неизвестно есть ли уже другие get параметры.

```
if (strpos($url, '?')) {
        $url = $url . '&lang=ru';
    }
    else {
        $url = $url . '?lang=ru';
    }
```

Сделал вот так, но не думаю, что это лучшее решение.

Comment: Все уже придумано до нас http://php.net/manual/fa/function.http-build-url.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$add = 'lang=ru';
$url = (isset($_SERVER["QUERY_STRING"])? '&' : '?';
$url.=$add;
```

Comment: те же яйца, только в профиль.

Comment: ну тут любое решение будут одни и те же яйца ))) просто strpos будет медленнее, чем просто проверить наличие

Comment: О да, дикий удар по перформансу. А если надо добавить GET-параметр к не-текущему URL?

Comment: а к нетекущему зачем добавлять-то?? кошечки-божечки

Answer (score 1):

Я вот такую функцию использую.
Работает дольше Вашего варианта, но зато в строке не будет повторяющихся параметров.

```
    /** z_add_url_get
    *
    * @param $a_data - массив с данными которые должны быть добавлены к строке
    * @param $url - адрес страницы, если false то берется текущтй url
    * 
    *
    **/
    function z_add_url_get($a_data,$url = false){
        $http = $_SERVER['HTTPS'] ? 'https':'http';

if($url === false){
                   $url = $http.'://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
            }
        $query_str = parse_url($url);
        $path = !empty($query_str['path']) ? $query_str['path'] : '';
        $return_url = $query_str['scheme'].'://'.$query_str['host'].$path;
        $query_str = !empty($query_str['query']) ? $query_str['query'] : false;
        $a_query = array();
        if($query_str) {
            parse_str($query_str,$a_query);
        }
        $a_query = array_merge($a_query,$a_data);
        $s_query = http_build_query($a_query);
        if($s_query){
        $s_query = '?'.$s_query;    
        }
        return $return_url.$s_query;
        }

           $url = 'http://z-site.ru/?my_param=hello&my_param_2=bye';
           echo  z_add_url_get(array('my_param_2'=>'goodbye','new_param'=>'this is new param'),$url); // http://z-site.ru/?my_param=hello&my_param_2=goodbye&new_param=this+is+new+param

           $url = 'http://z-site.ru/';
           echo  z_add_url_get(array('my_param_2'=>'goodbye','new_param'=>'this is new param'),$url); // http://z-site.ru/?my_param_2=goodbye&new_param=this+is+new+param
```

Comment: Вместо REQUEST_SCHEME лучше полагаться на элемент HTTPS из того же $_SERVER
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18008135/is-serverrequest-scheme-reliable

Comment: @Fike Спасибо, поправил.

Answer (score 0):

```
$url = "//$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";
$add = 'export=1';
$url .= ( isset( $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'] ) ) ? "&$add" : "?$add";
```

Comment: Это же только для текущего url работает, а нигде не говорится, что к нему надо добавить.

Comment: Так, стоп. Не надо чужие ответы копипастить. Хотя.. Он всё-таки немного изменён...

Answer (score 0):

Правильно сделать так:

```
$url .= (strpos($url, '?') === false ? '?' : '&') . 'lang=ru'
```

Надо проверять на `false` через `===`, поскольку `strpos` может ещё вернуть 0 в случае, когда строка начинается с искомого символа.

Впрочем, если речь идёт о полном адресе, то он с вопроса начинаться не может, так что можно этот момент проигнорировать и написать просто

```
$url .= (strpos($url, '?') ? '&' : ':') . 'lang=ru'
```

хотя я бы так делать не рекомендовал.

Answer (score 0):

У меня сейчас нет возможности проверить. Требуемая функция отключена на всех песочницах для исполнения PHP, которые я нашел. Но должно работать как то так.

```
$url = "https://mysite.com/?param1=qwe&param2=asd";
$resUrl = http_build_url($url,
    array(
        "query" => "param1=zxc&param3=123"
    ),
    HTTP_URL_JOIN_QUERY
);
echo $resUrl;
```

Если я правильно понял описание, данный код должен вернуть одно из двух:

либо

> https://mysite.com/?param1=qwe&param2=asd&param1=zxc&param3=123

либо

> https://mysite.com/?param1=zxc&param2=asd&param3=123

Если вы получите ошибку

> Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function
>   http_build_url()

значит у вас отключены функции http.

Что с этим делать читайте здесь https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14056977/function-http-build-url

Answer (score 0):

Из примеров php.net:

> Возьмем `$url = 'http://username:password@hostname:9090/path?arg=value#anchor';`. Рассмотрим функцию `parse_url`. Начиная с PHP 8.0.0, parse_url() различает отсутствующие и пустые запросы и фрагменты:
>
> ```
> http://example.com/foo → query = null, fragment = null
> http://example.com/foo? → query = "",   fragment = null
> http://example.com/foo# → query = null, fragment = ""
> http://example.com/foo?# → query = "",   fragment = ""
> ```

В примере со ссылкой с php.net выше, при использовании кода вы получите `?arg=value#anchor&lang=ru`. В случае отсутствия get параметров `?lang=ru`

Поэтому помощью функции `parse_url` в сочетании с константой `PHP_URL_QUERY` можно проверить, заданы ли у нас какие-либо get параметры. При использовании кода ниже (он уже от меня), можно либо объявить блок get параметров с помощью знака `?`, либо подставлять новый get параметр

```
$url = '';
$url .= (parse_url($url, PHP_URL_QUERY)) ? '&' : '?';
$url .= 'lang=ru';
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять более развёрнутые ответы. Дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: @PetəíŕdTheLinuxWizard
ready. Можете отзывать свои жалобы

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin ready. Можете отзывать свои жалобы